# Umount не пашет BASH

Tags: linux, bash

Не работает umount

не могу понять в чем проблема

пробовал umount -f 'path' и umount -l 'path'
тоже ничего, пишет device is busy

также пробовал посмотреть PID процесса через lsof, там тоже ничего не показало...

Что интересно, если написать в самом ШЕЛЕ вручную sudo umount 'path' то все работает, а в sh скрипте нет..

Comment: и под sudo тоже?

Comment: да, я поправил вопрос

Comment: а из какой директории вызывали команду когда не работало и когда работало ?

Comment: хмм... странно, скрипт находится в папке bin, после завершения работы он должен отмонтировать раздел, сейчас добавил в конец скрипта строчку " cd .. " а потом umount, и теперь ошибка не вылазит...

Comment: в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: чувствую вы вызывали команды из той директории, которую нужно было отмонтировать, например, хотели `/mnt/cdrom` отмонтировать из директории `/mnt/cdrom`. нужно из другой попки попробовать. а ваш  скрипт был вызван из другой как раз

Comment: точно, спасибо .. глупость не заметил даже

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы вызывали команды из той директории, которую нужно было отмонтировать, например, хотели `/mnt/cdrom` отмонтировать из директории `/mnt/cdrom`. Нужно из другой попки попробовать, а ваш скрипт был вызван из другой как раз

p.s.  после `sudo -s` вы переходите на другую директорию, поэтому оттуда удалось отмонтировать